# Why does concatenating these two strings shift the end 3 characters over the front 3 characters of the combined string in Go?

Tags: arrays, string, go, concatenation

When trying to concatenate two strings, they combine but the next three characters overwrite earlier concatenated text before again continuing to concatenate as expected.  I suspect this is something to do with the `retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index], var_swap)` function as this phenomena **only** happens when it is called within the double `for` of the `cmd.Interaction` section of `build_executable`.

**Where the error is**

```
func build_executable(cmd shell_command, var_swap string_matrix, is_first bool) string{
    sleep_duration := cmd.Sleep
    result := ""
    if !is_first{
        result = "send \""
    } else {
        result = "spawn "
    }
    result += cmd.Command
    if len(cmd.Options.Dashes) > 0 {
        for index := range cmd.Options.Dashes{
            if cmd.Options.Dashes[index] != "" || cmd.Options.Flags[index] != ""{
                result += " " + cmd.Options.Dashes[index] + cmd.Options.Flags[index]
            }
            if cmd.Options.Values[index] != ""{
                result += " " + cmd.Options.Values[index]
            }
        }
    }
    if len(cmd.Targets.Litteral) > 0{
        result += " "
        for index := range cmd.Targets.Litteral{
            result += cmd.Targets.Litteral[index] + retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Targets.Variable[index], var_swap)
        }
    }
    if !is_first{
        result += "\\r\"\n"
    } else {
        result += "\n"
    }
    result += "sleep " + sleep_duration + "\n"
    if len(cmd.Interaction.Prompts) > 0{
        for p_index := range cmd.Interaction.Prompts{
            fmt.Println("cmd.Interaction.Prompts[p_index]\t" + cmd.Interaction.Prompts[p_index])
            result += "expect \"" + cmd.Interaction.Prompts[p_index] + "\"\nsend \""
            for r_index := range cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral{
                fmt.Println("cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral[r_index]\t'" + cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral[r_index] + "'")
                fmt.Println("cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index]\t'" + cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index] + "'")
                fmt.Println("retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index], var_swap)\t'" + retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index], var_swap) + "'")
                result += cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral[r_index] 
                result += retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index], var_swap)
                result += "" + "" + ""
            }
            result += "\\r\"\nsleep " + sleep_duration + "\n"
        }
    }
    if cmd.Expects != "" {
        result += "expect \"" + cmd.Expects + "\"\n"
    }
    return result
}
```

**Suspect function**

```
func retrieve_mapped_value(key string, mapping string_matrix) string{
    if key != "" {
        for _, layer := range mapping{
            if layer[0] == key {
                return layer[1]
            }
        }
    } else {
        return key
    }
    return "***No Match Error***"
}
```

**What I should get**

```
expect "Enter password for user root: "
send "e3H-*HGHu__7\r"
sleep 10
```

**What I actually get**

```
expect "Enter password for user root: "
\r"d "e3H-*HGHu__7
sleep 10
```

It is taking the last 3 characters of one line and overwriting the front with them.  I don't understand.

Comment: `string_matrix` is  not defined.

Comment: Sanitize your input, e.g. remove control characters like backspaces or that like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the solution to this but the `temp_add` section of the below where I arbitrarily slice off the end of the string works.  There is some voodoo up in here.

```
func build_executable(cmd shell_command, var_swap string_matrix, is_first bool) string{
    sleep_duration := cmd.Sleep
    result := ""
    if !is_first{
        result = "send \""
    } else {
        result = "spawn "
    }
    result += cmd.Command
    if len(cmd.Options.Dashes) > 0 {
        for index := range cmd.Options.Dashes{
            if cmd.Options.Dashes[index] != "" || cmd.Options.Flags[index] != ""{
                result += " " + cmd.Options.Dashes[index] + cmd.Options.Flags[index]
            }
            if cmd.Options.Values[index] != ""{
                result += " " + cmd.Options.Values[index]
            }
        }
    }
    if len(cmd.Targets.Litteral) > 0{
        result += " "
        for index := range cmd.Targets.Litteral{
            result += cmd.Targets.Litteral[index] + retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Targets.Variable[index], var_swap)
        }
    }
    if !is_first{
        result += "\\r\"\n"
    } else {
        result += "\n"
    }
    result += "sleep " + sleep_duration + "\n"
    if len(cmd.Interaction.Prompts) > 0{
        for p_index := range cmd.Interaction.Prompts{
            interaction_result := "expect \"" + cmd.Interaction.Prompts[p_index] + "\"\nsend \""
            temp_add := ""
            for r_index := range cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral{
                interaction_result += cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Litteral[r_index]
                temp_add = retrieve_mapped_value(cmd.Interaction.Replies[p_index].Variable[r_index], var_swap)
                if temp_add != ""{      //this looks wasteful but it is needed for reasons I don't understand
                    temp_add += "\n"    //the basic explaination is it seems `retrieve_mapped_value` appends a carriage return & this
                    temp_add = temp_add[:len(temp_add) - 2]     //messes up the script, I don't know why it appends it, but removes it
                }
                interaction_result += temp_add
            }
            interaction_result += "\\r\"\nsleep " + sleep_duration + "\n"
            result += interaction_result
        }
    }
    if cmd.Expects != "" {
        result += "expect \"" + cmd.Expects + "\"\n"
    }
    return result
}
```